# How to use tensorflow debugging tool tfdbg on tf.estimator in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am working with Tensorflow version 1.4, and I want to debug my `train()` function.

In this link https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger#debugging_tf-learn_estimators_and_experiments

there is a way to do it for `tf.contrib.learn Estimators`, but I can not find a way to adapt it to the (new in version 1.4) `tf.estimator`.

This is what I have tried:

```
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug

# Create an estimator
my_estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, 
                                      params=model_params,
                                      model_dir='/tb_dir',
                                      config=config_estimator)

# Create a LocalCLIDebugHook and use it as a hook when calling train().
hooks = [tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook()]

# Train
my_estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10,hooks=hooks)
```

But I am running into this error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- error 
Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-14-71325f3c8f14> in <module>()
>       7 
>       8 # Train
> ----> 9 my_estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10,hooks=hooks)
> 
[...]
> 
> /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/curses_ui.py
> in _screen_launch(self, enable_mouse_on_start)
>     443 
>     444     curses.noecho()
> --> 445     curses.cbreak()
>     446     self._stdscr.keypad(1)
>     447 
> 
> error: cbreak() returned ERR
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default is set for working in command line, if you use IDE such as Pycharm the simplest solution is to change UI type.

Try:

```
hooks = [tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook(ui_type="readline")]
```

instead of:

```
hooks = [tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook()]
```

In case you use Pycharm, add to the configuration parameters --debug

Comment: I am working with a Jupyter notebook, and yes it is working with your solution. Thanks