# Why do I get "_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR" when using TensorFlow CLI Debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow, ncurses

I am trying to use the TensorFlow CLI debugger in order to identify the operation which is causing a NaN during training of a network, but when I try to run the code I get an error:

`_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR`

I'm running the code on an Ubuntu server, which I'm connecting to via SSH, and have tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/debugger).

I have tried using `tf.add_check_numerics_ops()`, but the layers in the network include while loops so are not compatible. This is the section of code where the error is being raised:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
...
#Prepare data
train_data, val_data, test_data = dataset.prepare_datasets(model_config)

sess = tf.Session()
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)

# Create iterators
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, train_data.output_types, train_data.output_shapes)
mixed_spec, voice_spec, mixed_audio, voice_audio = iterator.get_next()

training_iterator = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
validation_iterator = val_data.make_initializable_iterator()
testing_iterator = test_data.make_initializable_iterator()

training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
...
```

and the full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    @ex.automain
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sacred/experiment.py", line 137, in automain
    self.run_commandline()
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sacred/experiment.py", line 260, in run_commandline
    return self.run(cmd_name, config_updates, named_configs, {}, args)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sacred/experiment.py", line 209, in run
    run()
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sacred/run.py", line 221, in __call__
    self.result = self.main_function(*args)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sacred/config/captured_function.py", line 46, in captured_function
    result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 95, in do_experiment
    training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/framework.py", line 455, in run
    is_callable_runner=bool(callable_runner)))
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/local_cli_wrapper.py", line 255, in on_run_start
    self._run_start_response = self._launch_cli()
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/local_cli_wrapper.py", line 431, in _launch_cli
    title_color=self._title_color)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/curses_ui.py", line 492, in run_ui
    self._screen_launch(enable_mouse_on_start=enable_mouse_on_start)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/acvn728/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/debug/cli/curses_ui.py", line 445, in _screen_launch
    curses.cbreak()
_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR
```

I'm pretty new to using Ubuntu (and TensorFlow), but as far as I can tell the server does have ncurses installed, which should allow the required curses based interface:

```
acvn728@america:~/MScFinalProject$ dpkg -l '*ncurses*' | grep '^ii'
ii  libncurses5:amd64  6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncursesw5:amd64 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  ncurses-base       6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 all          basic terminal type definitions
ii  ncurses-bin        6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 amd64        terminal-related programs and man pages
ii  ncurses-term       6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1 all          additional terminal type definitions
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use tensorflow debugging tool tfdbg on tf.estimator in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833697/how-to-use-tensorflow-debugging-tool-tfdbg-on-tf-estimator-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved! The solution was to change

```
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
```

to

```
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess, ui_type="readline")
```

This is similar to the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833697/how-to-use-tensorflow-debugging-tool-tfdbg-on-tf-estimator-in-tensorflow), but I I think it is important to note that they are different because a) it refers to a different function and a different API and b) I wasn't trying to run from an IDE, as mentioned in that solution.

Answer (score 4):

`cbreak` would return **`ERR`** if you run a curses application that is not on a *real terminal* (i.e., something that works with [POSIX termios calls](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11)).

From the description,

> but the layers in the network include while loops so are not compatible

it does not seem you are running in a terminal.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what this means, could you please clarify? I am running the code in PuTTY, I don't know if this is a real terminal. I'm not sure the line you have quoted is relevant; it refers to the structure of the neural network model, not the interface I am executing the program from.

Comment: If you're connecting to PuTTY via a socket which doesn't **act** like a terminal, ncurses cannot tell that it is a terminal.  For debugging, it helps if you can run a shell (bash, csh) on the output terminal instead of the ncurses application, and see what **`stty`** shows.