I receive error on nocbreak() returned ERR from curses library running a configuration tool
I am trying to run a configuration tool that uses curses, but I get some kind of error, where strace shows the following:
10:49:05.285312 write(2, "Traceback (most recent call last"..., 477Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 78, in wrapper
    cbreak()
_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/nvidia/jetson-io/jetson-io.py", line 594, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(JetsonIO)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 100, in wrapper
    nocbreak()
_curses.error: nocbreak() returned ERR
) = 477

I am using Ubuntu 18.04
Do I need to install something else to get it to run?
I have tried installing ncurses and running the program with different permissions.

This might be of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747655/why-do-i-get-curses-error-cbreak-returned-err-when-using-tensorflow-cli-de

This question is similar to: Why do I get "_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR" when using TensorFlow CLI Debugger?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Turns out I got an error from another library, but there were no error messages or stacktrace except the curses ones. Fixing the library error the script worked.
